# PHP filtering - detecting filter failures

Tags: php

Update: It appears I had snipped out the wrong parts when whittling this down to a short/concise example.

I appears to (incorrectly!!) used `if(empty(0))` to detect validation failure when using `filter_var_array` and `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT`.

How would be best to do so?

http://codepad.viper-7.com/Z8MLLj

```
    $positiveIntegerFilter = array('filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
        'options' => array(
            'min_range' => 0
        )
    );

    $filter = array(
        'apples' => $positiveIntegerFilter,
        'oranges' => $positiveIntegerFilter, 
        'pears' => $positiveIntegerFilter, 
        'bananas' => $positiveIntegerFilter,
        'tangerine' => $positiveIntegerFilter
        );

    $values = Array(
        "apples" => 2,
        "oranges" => 4,
        "pears" => 0,
        "bananas" => -2, 
        "grapefruit" => 1
    );


    //Apply filter, and return only what validates
    $filteredValues = filter_var_array( $values, $filter );

    echo "values: ";
    print_r($values);
    echo "<br/>";

    echo "filteredValues: ";
    print_r($filteredValues);
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<br/>";


    //Examine filtered array for missing parts
    foreach($filter as $key => $value) {
        echo "key = " . $key . "  // value = " . $filteredValues[$key]  . "(" . (gettype($filteredValues[$key])) .")". "<br/>" . PHP_EOL;

        if(empty($filteredValues[$key])) { //should test if(!isset()) ?
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Invalid information object on key: `" . $key . "`");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which PHP version did you test this on?

Comment: PHP Version 5.6.3 (on a Windows / XAMPP 5.6.3 install, if that's at all relevant?)

Comment: Yes, I cannot reproduce that issue using every version on http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZKvaQ6

Comment: There were some changes in how zero values got treated differently prior 5.4, not relevant here. -- However, your result array should carry `false` values for the two unvalidated entries, if anything. Which it doesn't. So you're likely filtering it again somehow (array_filter?) in the function.

Comment: It may be a case that I have removed the part causing the issue when trying to whittle the example down to something simple/anonymous. I'll take another look and edit the original post to include an alternate example.

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify that it was me being silly.. Could you advise on the best way to detect and handle validation failures? Is the above approach reasonable?